# Dataframe stripplot works, but boxplot and swarmplot dont

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I have a dataframe of values of +100 animals which I want to plot some data of using `seaborn` in a Jupyter notebook.

Here's a redacted and condensed copy of the dataframe (removed some columns and rows, copied from the output of `df.to_dense()`). This data still shows the problem I have.

```
            CoEx   Body weight  Day
asdf-C-4a   Co      12.99        4
asdf-C-4e   Co      14.22        4
asdf-E-4d   Ex      11.26        4
asdf-C-10c  Co      20.2        10
asdf-E-10b  Ex      24.9        10
asdf-C-21a  Co      82.9        21
asdf-C-21e  Co      73.6        21
asdf-E-21d  Ex      69          21
asdf-C-60c  Co     410          60
asdf-E-60b  Ex     350          60
```

When I now do a `seaborn.stripplot(data=df, x='Day', y='Body weight', hue='CoEx')` I get what I want (minus some styling, but that's not the issue here).

[image: stripplot, works]

Now I would love to have either a `boxplot` or `swarmplot` of the data, but none of them works.

With `seaborn.boxplot(data=df, x='Day', y='Body weight', hue='CoEx')` I get an `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'find'`.
With `seaborn.swarmplot(data=df, x='Day', y='Body weight', hue='CoEx')` I get a `ValueError: object too deep for desired array`.

With both box- and swarmplot I get an output if I omit the `x`, `y` and `hue` specifications (image below for `seaborn.boxplot(data=df)`), but that's obviously not the data I want to show, I want to split the values over the different experiment days.

[image]

Any tips on how I can boxplot this dataset, split over the days and hued with either control or experiment?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Both `boxplot` and `violinplot` return the desired output with the data provided. Using seaborn 0.7.1 and matplotlib 2.0.2

Comment: It could be an issue with multi-indexing? Maybe rather create a minimal complete viable example in code that replicates the error on your side. So instead of pasting the data as text give it to us as runnable code like `df=pd.DataFrame(...`

Comment: After outputting the dataframe to a string and reading this string back into a new dataframe I *can* do the violinplots. One of my problems seem to be that the research data (which I cannot share) is read from several sheets of one (big and messy) XLS file. Here's an 'as minimal as possible' copy of the notebook: https://gist.github.com/habi/6a8f4948ed6ce9e2d605d9dfa68e1254 Any tips on properly reading the XLS sheets into a dataframe to solve my problem?